# Definition of a linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

$f:K^n \rightarrow K $ is a linear application of $K^n$ to $K$ iff there exist $a_1...a_n \in K$ s.t. for each $x \in K^n$ we have:

$$f(x_1, ... x_n) = a_1  x_1 + ... + a_n  x_n.$$

Now I am confused about what is a vector and what is a scalar in this definition. $(x_1, ... x_n)$ is obviously a vector, but what about an individual $x_1$? Shouldn't it be a scalar? Also, what is the output of this function? Is it a one-dimensional vector? A scalar? Are the two the same thing?

Also, I know that $K$ is a vector space on itself, so does this imply anything?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a different concept from "linear transformation" or "linear map"?

Comment: I dont think so... (But I am translating this from French)

Comment: $x_1$ is the first coordinate of the vector $(x_1, \dots,x_n)\in K_n$. It can be considered a vector in the one-dimensional vector space $K$ or as a scalar, depending on the context.

Comment: French *application* is *map* or *mapping* in English.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to consider that these coefficients are natural.

Any linear application $f$ from $K^n$ to $K^p$ can be represented by a matrix with $p$ lines and $n$ columns. Here $p=1$, thus, its matrix has the following form

$$(a_1 \ a_2 \ \cdots \ a_n)$$

When applied to a (column) vector of $K^n$:

$$(a_1 \ a_2 \ \cdots \ a_n)\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_n}=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots +a_nx_n$$

it naturally gives back a scalar $\in K$.